# Can I use a namespaced class with stream_wrapper_register?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-stream-wrappers

I have a class VarStream that I would like to register like

```
stream_wrapper_register('var', 'VarStream');
```

Our classes are always namespaced, so I've tried

```
stream_wrapper_register('var', '\OurSpace\VarStream');
```

with no luck.

Can I use namespacing when registering a stream wrapper?

Comment: anyone? are bumps permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to provide the [FQCN (Fully-Qualified-Class-Name)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) of the stream wrapper class.

You might think that in the code you provided you have it already:

```
stream_wrapper_register('var', '\OurSpace\VarStream');
```

But that is not the case as the FQCN never starts with the back-slash "`\`".

Instead use (just) the class-name of that class:

```
stream_wrapper_register('var', 'OurSpace\VarStream');
```

Normally the leading backslash is not necessary. In this case even, it prevents proper use. It is *not* part of the (fully-qualified) class-name. This is normally always the case when you pass class-names as string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved such problem with usage of [::class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), which

> allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile

For example,

```
stream_wrapper_register("stream", self::class)
```

So you don't have to think about (back)slashes by yourself ;]